# Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option UseSplitVerifier; support was removed in 8.0 error in Grails

Tags: ubuntu, grails, amazon-web-services, stack-trace, grails-controller

I am trying to run a simple HelloWorld grails app on AWS Ubuntu instance . The code can be found at : https://github.com/paulnguyen/cloud/tree/master/grails/helloworld-grails

I have installed following version of grails and java :

```
| Grails Version: 3.1.1
| Groovy Version: 2.4.5
| JVM Version: 1.8.0_65
```

I am navigating to the main root directory of this github repository and trying to run "grails compile" . 
It gives an error as : **`Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option UseSplitVerifier; support was removed in 8.0 ( Error occurred running Grails CLI: null (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace))`**

Can someone tell me where am I going wrong ? 
Am I going wrong someone in the execution of steps for deployment?
I need to deploy this simple app on AWS.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the application.properties file, it appears that the helloworld project is written for Grails 2.4.3, not 3.1.1. Basically, you are using the wrong version of grails and need to use an older version.